# How to print error message near UI elements in R shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

An example code:

ui.R

```
library(shiny) 

shinyUI(
  fluidRow(column(2, actionButton("add", "ADD details")), 
           fluidRow(uiOutput("ui"))
  )  
)
```

server.R

```
shinyServer(function(input, output,session){
  observeEvent(
    input$add,
    output$ui <- renderUI({
      isolate({
        fluidRow(column(4, textInput("birthweight", label = "birth weight:", value = '')), 
                 column(3, numericInput("height",label = "Height:",value='')),
                 column(2, actionButton("addnew", "ADD details to database")) 
        )
      })
    })
  )
})
```

When the user enters the input to `birthweight` an error message should be displayed near the `textInput` box if it contains character data, similarly for `numericInput` `Height`. This must be displayed as soon as the user enters the data or when the user clicks the add details to database action button, but should be displayed as an error message near the textbox not in a pop up window.

Can this be done in R shiny?

Comment: Have you tried http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/validation.html?

Answer (score 4):

The `validate` function is one options. Another options is use an extra UI to show a error message only if the textInput has a no-numeric value. In this case you can add you own CCS to the error message. Here is an example based on your code.

```R
library(shiny)    
ui <-shinyUI(  
  fluidRow( 
    column(2, 
      actionButton("add", "ADD details")),
    fluidRow( uiOutput("ui"))
  )
)    

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output,session){
  observeEvent( input$add,
    output$ui <- renderUI({
      isolate({
        fluidRow( 
          column(4, 
            textInput("birthweight", label = "birth weight:", value = ''),
            uiOutput("checkBirthweight")), 
          column(3, 
            numericInput("height",label = "Height:",value='')),
          column(2, 
            actionButton("addnew", "ADD details to database")) 
        )
      })
    })
  )

  output$checkBirthweight <- renderUI({
    if (nchar(input$birthweight) > 0 && is.na(as.numeric(input$birthweight)))
      p("Error: birth weight must be numeric")
  })

})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

By the way, it is good idea to put your code as code in your questions, it will helps to others to identify the problem. You can find extra help about that at https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Also, I know that everybody has its own code style and I respect that, but I found these guidelines for coding in R very useful https://google.github.io/styleguide/Rguide.xml